# Respond like Clyde

Tags: python, discord.py

i tried to make a respond like Clyde, which only the ctx.author can see. This is what i tried:

```
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
   author = ctx.author
   await author.reply('Hallo')
```

But the code gives me an error, that *Member object has no attribute reply*. Can anyonel please help me?

Comment: What does respond like Clyde mean? Do you want to hide the message or do you want to DM the user?

Comment: I want the Bot to reply the user, but only the user can see the reply

Comment: @ItIzYe Just say `hidden=True`?

Comment: hidden= True doesnt work, bc it isnt in the discord.py

Comment: You have to use slash commands in order to hide the message and YES, it is in `discord.py`...

Comment: So which libary do i have to use? Interactions from Rapptz?

Comment: You have to use `discord.py`? [Link](https://github.com/discord-py-slash-commands/discord-py-interactions)

Comment: But what excactly do i have to import bc it doesnt work if i just use discord

Comment: and it doesnt work with the Libary you linked

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are meaing to reply to the message, not DM the user. This can be done by calling `reply()` on `ctx` instead of `ctx.author`, so just do this:

```
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
   await ctx.reply('Hallo')
```

Comment: Well, yes, i mean reply, but the reply should only be visible for the ctx.author.